# Derivation of 9 point Laplacian filter

Tags: fourier-transform, laplace-transform, numerical-algorithms, finite-differences, anisotropic-diffusion

I'm reading a [paper on how construct isotropic laplacian filter](https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1928&context=cstech), and perhaps because it's an old paper, the notation in it really bothers me a lot. So can someone please explain it to me? For example, the notations I have highlighted in redline in the screenshot, such as what G and U mean and how to interpret these equations. I have no idea what these equation really means and how I should go about understanding it.
[image]

Comment: This appears to be a two-dimensional convolution with 3×3 matrix.  Is that correct?  What is this 2-D filtering supposed to accomplish?  Interpolation?  Something else?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Yeah. This is used to build an 9 point stencil (isotropic)laplacian filter.